# What is the column limit for Spark Data Frames?

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql

Our team is having a lot of issues with the Spark API particularly with large schema tables. We currently have a program written in Scala that utilizes the Apache spark API to create two Hive tables from raw files. We have one particularly very large raw data file that is giving us issues that contains around ~4700 columns and ~200,000 rows.

Every week we get a new file that shows the updates, inserts and deletes that happened in the last week. Our program will create two tables – a master table and a history table. The master table will be the most up to date version of this table while the history table shows all changes inserts and updates that happened to this table and showing what changed. For example, if we have the following schema where A and B are the primary keys:

```
      Week 1                      Week 2
|-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
|  A  |  B  |  C  |         |  A  |  B  |  C  |
|-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
|  1  |  2  |  3  |         |  1  |  2  |  4  |
|-----|-----|-----|         |-----|-----|-----|
```

Then the master table will now be

```
|-----|-----|-----|      
|  A  |  B  |  C  |       
|-----|-----|-----|       
|  1  |  2  |  4  |       
|-----|-----|-----|
```

And The history table will be

```
|-----|-----|-------------------|----------------|-------------|-------------|      
|  A  |  B  |  changed_column   |  change_type   |  old_value  |  new_value  |     
|-----|-----|-------------------|----------------|-------------|-------------|      
|  1  |  2  |        C          |    Update      |     3       |     4       |
|-----|-----|-------------------|----------------|-------------|-------------|
```

This process is working flawlessly for shorter schema tables. We have a table that has 300 columns but over 100,000,000 rows and this code still runs as expected. The process above for the larger schema table runs for around 15 hours, and then crashes with the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.loop$1(Growable.scala:52)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:57)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:183)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ListBuffer.scala:45)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:381)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:344)
```

Here is a code example that takes around 4 hours to run for this larger table, but runs in 20 seconds for other tables:

```
var dataframe_result = dataframe1.join(broadcast(dataframe2), Seq(listOfUniqueIds:_*)).repartition(100).cache()
```

We have tried all of the following with no success:

- Using hash broad-cast joins (dataframe2 is smaller, dataframe1 is huge)
- Repartioining on different numbers, as well as not repartitioning at all
- Caching the result of the dataframe (we originally did not do this).

What is causing this error and how can we fix it? The only difference between this problem table is that it has so many columns. Is there an upper limit to how many columns Spark can handle?

Note: We are running this code on a very large MAPR cluster and we tried giving the code 500GB of RAM and its still failing.

Comment: Back when using Spark 1 and some specific dataset, I remember having Stack Overflows when one of my RDD rows would contain a standard (immutable) scala Collection like List/Seq[_] beyond a certain length. I remember tracing it down to a recursive implementation of the serialization process, which could not, of course, scale up forever. I really don't know if this still happens, or even if it can happen on Dataframes, but you might want to check (convert each to the mutable.[Collection]) if you suspect one is bound to get very large.